# Showing that the n first derivatives of (x²-1)^n have at least r roots (for the r-th derivative)?

Tags: analysis, polynomials, derivatives, roots

I have f(x) = (x²-1)^n. I want to show that, for r = 0,1,2,...,n, the r-th derivative is a polynomial (that's easy to show) that has no fewer than r distinct roots in (-1,1).
I guess I need to use induction here. I've showed that these derivatives have actually no more than r distinct roots but I can't show the actual result...
My only idea was to use the Rolle's Theorem but it does not ensure enough roots..

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: Show and use that all these derivatives have roots at $\pm1$. Apply Rolle's theorem.

Comment: I have showed that pretty easily. But then Rolle's theorem tells me that there exists some root of the next derivative in the interval... ... Do I not need to show that this x is a new root?

Comment: The point is that for the first derivative you get at least one root inside $(-1,1)$. That makes 3 roots in total in  $[-1,1]$. Now the second derivative has at least 2 roots inside $(-1,1)$, and therefore 4 in  $[-1,1]$. etc.

Comment: owwwwwwwwwwww yes, of course! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Fleshing out Lutzl's comment:

The $0$-th derivative trivially has 0 or more distinct roots in $(-1,1)$.

Assume the $r$-th derivative has $r$ or more distinct roots in $(-1, 1)$.

The $r$-th derivative is going to be multiple of $(x^2-1)$ (for $r <= n-1$).

So it has at least $r+2$ distinct zeroes in $[-1,1]$ (because $\pm1$ are additional roots).

By Rolle's theorem, there are zeroes of the $(r+1)$-th derivative between each of those pairs of roots of the $r$-th derivative. Since the $(r+1)$-th derivative's zeroes are strictly between those of the $r$-th derivative, they are in $(-1,1)$ and distinct. So we've found that there are at least $r+1$ distinct roots of the $(r+1)$-th derivative in $(-1,1)$. Thus by induction, the $r$-th derivative has at least $r$ distinct roots in $(-1,1)$ if $r <= n$.